# Get First 3 items of backbone collection in Underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, rendering, underscore.js

```
{{_.each(model, function(item) { }}
<h5 style="color:#F30;">{{=item.name}}</h5> 
        {{for  (i = 0; i < item.subcollection.length; i++) {  }}  
               <li><a>{{=item.subcollection[i].split('#')[0]}}</a></li>
         {{ } }} 
{{ });}}
```

I have underscore template for rendering backbone model collection which contains a subcollection inside.But i need render only first 3 collection while rendering. ny help

Comment: u need to render first 3 item form `item.subcollection` ?

Comment: @Evgeniy No, fron item model

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what you are trying to do but if you want only first three to be executed set the counter value to 3 instead collection.length

```
 {{for(j=0;j<3;j++){ }}
<h5 style="color:#F30;">{{=model[j].name}}</h5> 
        {{for  (i = 0; i < model[j].subcollection.length; i++) {  }}  
               <li><a>{{=model[j].subcollection[i].split('#')[0]}}</a></li>
         {{ } }} 
{{ } }}
```

note : make sure the length is at least 3.

Comment: Thanks, but its for subcollection but i need from model item

Comment: are really talking about underscore templates

Comment: sorry , are you really talking about underscore templates data rendering ?

Comment: @CharlotteEden was your question about underscore templates?

Comment: yes. its really about rendering data in a underscore template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67116/discussion-between-aktiv-coder-and-charlotte-eden).

Comment: @CharlotteEden if you got your answer , can you accept my answer?

Comment: sure, i will accept your answer, but so far i didn't